# LOF: Formatting Figurenames and adding Column Names

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Here is the specific format I have to apply to the LOF:
It should be Basically 3 aligned columns that contain: page number - figure number - the figure name (in this very order, like a tabular).
And I need to display the names of the columns.

---

## List of Figures

**Page  Figure#  Figure name**

 

  1         1              thename_of_figure1


  8         2              thename_of_figure2
that does not fit on

                             a single line

15         3              thename_of_figure3

16         4              thename_of_figure4

---

Currently, I have the following `\titlecontents` configuration (I have struggled to reach this alignement of the 3 columns: Hopefuly it was the correct way to do it!=)

```
\titlecontents{figure}
[0em]
{}
{\thecontentspage{\ifthenelse{\thecontentspage<10}{\hspace*{6ex}}{\hspace*{5ex}}}%
\thecontentslabel{\ifthenelse{\thecontentslabel<10}{\hspace*{6ex}}{\hspace*{5ex}}}}%
{}
{}
```

which display the following :

---

## List of Figures

1         1              thename_of_figure1


  8         2              thename_of_figure2
that does not fit on

                             a single line

15         3              thename_of_figure3

16         4              thename_of_figure4

---

Now, I need help for...

1. adding the **Page Figure#  Figure name** headers, and
2. aligning the rest of the title that does not fit on the line, so that it is placed just below the very first letter of the title.

Comment: It works great ! Thanks you all for your pretty quick response !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the contents of the above image. Hope this is what you want.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newlength{\digitlen}
\settowidth{\digitlen}{1}

\titlecontents{figure}
[0em]
{}
{\contentspush{%
 \ifthenelse{\thecontentspage<10}{\hspace*{\digitlen}}{}%
 \thecontentspage\hspace*{4.5em}%
 \ifthenelse{\thecontentslabel<10}{\hspace*{\digitlen}}{}%
 \thecontentslabel\hspace*{5em}}}
{}
{}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace*{1em}}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\textbf{Page}\hspace*{2em}\textbf{Figure \#}\hspace*{2em}\textbf{Figure name}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace*{1em}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure\ which is very very very very very long}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{the name of figure\thefigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Downvote because reposting someone else's answer with a slightly more elaborate example is not a nice thing to do.

Comment: @elemakil The truth is that I was working at the answer and, when I posted it, I didn't ever noticed that you already posted yours, since I had the page opened in the browser and I didn't refreshed it. Do you really think that I've used your answer to make mine? If yes, you don't know me at all... And anyway, +1 to your answer.

Comment: Alright, sorry for misjudging. I noticed your answer popping up about an hour after mine. Indeed I don't know you at all (how should I?). My apologies, again.

Comment: @elemakil I'm here just to try to help someone with my little knowledge, not to steal answers or reputation from other users. And anyway you didn't retract your downvote...

Comment: Will do once I can... ;-) It says my vote is locked (since I voted only 15 hrs ago), damn yee technology!

Comment: @elemakil Thank you twice: 1. for having explained your downvote. 2. for having retracted it after clarifying. :-)

Comment: Only one things : the addtocontentline does not appear at the first line... when a figure is put at the very first page of the book. In this case, the added line (header) appears in second position. When the figure is in page 2 : it works fine ! 
Any ideas ?

Comment: @user39453 In this case you can move the 3 lines `\addtocontents...\addtocontents` inside the first `figure`, but before the `\caption`!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how sound my solution is, but it works:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% Your packages ...

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{figure}
[0em]
{}
{\contentspush{\thecontentspage{\ifthenelse{\thecontentspage<10}{\hspace*{6ex}}{\hspace*{5ex}}}%
    \thecontentslabel{\ifthenelse{\thecontentslabel<10}{\hspace*{6ex}}{\hspace*{5ex}}}}}%
{}
{}

\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\footnotesize\normalfont\bfseries Page \hspace*{1ex} Figure \# \hspace*{1ex} Figure Name}{}{}}

\begin{document}


\listoffigures

% Your document--

\end{document}
```

And here's and example:

[image: LoF Test]

Some Notes:

- The command `\contentspush` prints its argument and shifts the following stuff by the width of that text to the right (cf. [it's documentation](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf))
- I did not fiddle around with the size of the legend and the offsets between the words but you can easily change the font size to something smaller than `\footnotesize` ([cf. Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text)) and adapt the `\hspace`'s
- You have to ensure that the `\addcontentsline` comes logically *before* the first picture is typeset or otherwise the legend will be printed *after* the entry corresponding to that figure

Answer (score 0):

I feel this can be done using a section* and table inserted after that as figure list. This should look like the way you want.

```
\section*{List of Figures}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \textbf{Page  } & \textbf{Figure\#} & \textbf{Figure name} \\
      1    &       1 & thename_of_figure1 \\
          &       &  \\
      8    &       2 & thename_of_figure2 that does not fit on \\
          &       & a single line \\
           &         &  \\
    15     &     3  & thename_of_figure3 \\
          &       & \\
    16    &      4  & thename_of_figure4 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

This is my first answer here .... so sorry if this was not what you asked

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants the LOF to be generated automatically and not write the corresponding table manually ;-)

Comment: ok .... me dumb :)

Answer (score 0):

The following MWE updates `\l@figure` which is used to set the LoF entries. An `\AtBeginDocument` write to the `.aux` (immediately) inserts the appropriate heading as well (**Page** ~ 30pt and **Figure** ~ 40pt):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fig}[1][A figure]{% Just for this example
  \begin{figure}\centering\rule{.6\linewidth}{.15\textheight}\caption{#1}\end{figure}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % LoF heading
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{lof}{{\string\bfseries%
    \string\makebox[30pt]{Page}%
    \string\makebox[40pt]{Figure}%
    Figure name}\string\par\string\bigskip\string\ignorespaces\string\noindent}}%
}
\renewcommand{\l@figure}[2]{{%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}[2]{%
    \makebox[40pt]{##1}% Figure number
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-70pt}@{}}##2\end{tabular}\par}%
  \makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \makebox[30pt]{#2}% Page number
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-30pt]{#1}%
}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{A section}
\fig\fig\fig[A very long figure caption that should span multiple lines and break properly]
\fig\fig\fig[A very long figure caption that should span multiple lines and break properly]
\fig\fig\fig[A very long figure caption that should span multiple lines and break properly]
\fig\fig\fig[A very long figure caption that should span multiple lines and break properly]

\end{document}
```